# Force debug Administrator Malware

Tags: malware, unpacking, anti-debugging, patch-reversing, processhacker

I want to analyse a malware that do not run without administrative previliges.

I know it is risky but still.

How can I debug it with debugger as from entry point?

Because debugger could not start it as administrator. And I Got error

`Error Starting Process (create Process, 00000740, uiAccess="true")`

Comment: Why not to debug it in isolated environment? Like virtual machine

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas:

1. Try using [Image File Execution Options](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/101/2015/12/an-introduction-to-image-file-execution-options/) registry key  to automatically run the debugger when the process starts.
2. Patch an infinite loop (`EB FE`) at the entry point, start the binary, then attach to it from a debugger started as admin.
3. Use kernel debugger or hypervisor-based debugger to debug the process without relying on user mode debugging API.